# Return from select condition true or false

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(some_timestamp, true) as "isFinished"
from user_satus
where id = 3344 and some_timestamp > now()
```

it fails with next error:
COALESCE types timestamp with time zone and boolean cannot be matched.
what I need that is return true if `some_timestamp > now()` else false.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the rules would help.  Why would this code use `coalesce()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select (count(*) > 0) as "isFinished"
from user_satus
where id = 3344 and some_timestamp > now();
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
select exists (select 1
               from user_status
               where id = 3344 and some_timestamp > now()
              ) as isFinished;
```

Note:  The logic seems strange, to consider something finished if a timestamp is in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a boolean field that just checks if some time stamp is greater than current timestamp then you can use this.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN some_timestamp > now() THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS IS_FINISHED
    FROM USER_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT MAX(some_timestamp > NOW()) AS isFinished
FROM user_satus
WHERE id = 3344;
```